# Detecting Physics Contact in Swift 2

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skphysicscontact

I want to detect in my app a contact between two objects. I have an `enum` to define the different types:

```
enum ColliderType: UInt32 {

    case Ball = 0b010
    case Object = 0b001
    case Gap = 0b100

}
```

I also added `SKPhysicsContactDelegate` to my `SKView`:

In `didMoveToView`, I have

```
self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
```

So here are my objects that I defined

```
ball = SKSpriteNode(texture: ballTexture)
    ball.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(self.frame) - self.frame.width/12, y: self.frame.size.height - (self.frame.size.height - 100))
    ball.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: ballTexture.size().height)
    ball.physicsBody!.dynamic = false
    ball.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
    ball.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = ColliderType.Ball.rawValue
    ball.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = ColliderType.Object.rawValue
    ball.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = ColliderType.Object.rawValue


let boxTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "Obstacle.png")
    let box1 = SKSpriteNode(texture: boxTexture)
    box1.size = CGSizeMake(self.frame.width/4, self.frame.width/8)
    box1.runAction(moveAndRemoveBoxes)
    box1.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: box1.size)
    box1.physicsBody!.dynamic = false
    box1.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = ColliderType.Object.rawValue
    box1.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = ColliderType.Ball.rawValue
    box1.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = ColliderType.Object.rawValue

let gap = SKSpriteNode()
    gap.size = box1.size
    gap.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: box1.size)
    gap.physicsBody!.dynamic = false
    gap.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = ColliderType.Gap.rawValue
    gap.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = ColliderType.Ball.rawValue
    gap.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = ColliderType.Gap.rawValue
```

In the `didBeginContact` function I have:

```
func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {

    if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == ColliderType.Gap.rawValue || contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == ColliderType.Gap.rawValue {

        print("score")
        score++

        scoreLabel.text = String(score)

    } else {

        if gameOver == false {

            gameOver = true

            self.speed = 0


        }

    }
}
```

If you tap the screen the ball objects jumps from half of the screen to other, and the object called box1 is "falling down" on one half of the screen and the "invisible" gap to detect if the player passed without colliding with the box is on the other half of the screen. So I want to detect if the ball touches the gap, so that the players score, otherwise the ball collides with the box

Comment: Try replacing `case Ball = 0` with `case Ball = 0b010`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your obstacles contactTestBitMask is looking for Object, not Ball.  You want this: `box1.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = ColliderType.Ball.rawValue`

In light of the new changes:

`ball.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = ColliderType.Object.rawValue | ColliderType.Gap.rawValue`

You need to be checking for gap value if you want contact to work

Comment: This doesn't change anything unfortunately, I now set ball.dynamic to false, but I still don't get any output from didBeganContact. First I thought it worked but then I realized it was just the ball colliding with the view

Comment: well that is because you are not declaring your ball property correctly,  you can't have a value of 0 as a bit mask,  make it 0b010

Comment: What item is suppose to be colliding here?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add the gap object in the question

Comment: You really need to read up on sprite kit more before asking on SO,  you have zero idea on how your code works.  The only thing you are checking for in your contact is Gap, but none of your SpriteNodes are looking to contact Gap, so yes, it is always going to fail

Comment: It's basically the same code as in an example app that I downloaded, and this works. But thanks

Comment: on SO,  if you do not show that you are doing the research on your own, people will down vote your questions,  down voted questions tend to not get answered or are scrutinized by the community.  There are lots of tutorials out there

Comment: I'll delete this question